# Unknown type name error in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, synthesize

The goal of my app is to calculate two fields that will return in a text box. Unfortunately I'm receiving an error regarding with unknown type field referring to my TotalField.text field.  I have two views. One is the home screen which refers to the second view through a button and the second view contains these fields and labels that I'm trying to target.

This is my code.

**ViewController.h**

```
//  SalaryCalcApp
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Total;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *HourlyRate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *NumberOfHours;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *TotalField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *HourlyRateField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *NumberOfHoursField;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
//  SalaryCalcApp
//
// 
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end



@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@synthesize TotalField;
@synthesize Total;
@synthesize HourlyRate;
@synthesize NumberOfHours;
@synthesize HourlyRateField;
@synthesize NumberOfHoursField;

TotalField.text = [ NSString stringWthFormat:   @"%i", (HourlyRateField.text.intValue * NumberOfHoursField.text.intValue)   ];

@end
```

The error resides in this code:

```
TotalField.text = [ NSString stringWthFormat:   @"%i", (HourlyRateField.text.intValue * NumberOfHoursField.text.intValue)];
```

**Error Message:**

> Unknown type name 'TotalField' and Expected identifier or '('

Thank you everyone for your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Why is that code not nested inside a function?

Put it inside your viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    TotalField.text = [ NSString stringWthFormat:   @"%i", (HourlyRateField.text.intValue * NumberOfHoursField.text.intValue)   ];

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I didn't know that they were supposed to be placed in viewDidLoad. Although we have fixed this error, the application is still not calculating the two values. in these fields. Do you have any tips on how I can multiply these two integers from these two fields and display it in the Total Field?